# How do I install Python IDLE?

Tags: python, idle-python

Which IDLE package I should install from Software Center in Ubuntu assuming I want to program in Python 3?

Answer (score 21):

You can install IDLE for Python 3 by installing the `idle3` package in the official Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

For Python 2, replace `idle3` with `idle`.

Comment: When I ran the code and installed `idle3`, it also installed `idle-python3.4` alongside. I assume it is not `idle3` itself that actually runs when I run it on command terminal but rather `idle-python3.4`. `idle3` itself is just pointing at it. If a new version (say `idle-python3.5`) is released, it downloads that and `idle3` starts to point at that from that moment on as far as I understand. Is this correct?

Comment: @SarpSTA Yeah I would expect that to happen automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Use this package. Any of IDLE3 packages are fine. If you install IDLE3 it will get updated when they release a new version of IDLE3. But if you install IDLE(using Python-3.4), it won't get updated when IDLE for 3.5 is available.

[image]