# Where is IDLE (18.04)

Tags: python, python3, idle-python

My understanding was that IDLE comes built in with Python, which is installed with Ubuntu. I can't find IDLE in Applications. I can't find it to install in Ubuntu Software. Where is it? Not interested in workarounds. Want to know why it isn't there. Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/660414/idle-installation-in-ubuntu-14-04 - even though the question is about 14.04 the answers there still work on 18.04... the only difference is that there's no Python 2 version of IDLE in 18.04.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "workarounds", but you might need a pair of glasses. All versions of Idle are in the repos.

Comment: @JacobVlijm except Python2's IDLE in 18.04; Python 3 is the only IDLE available in 18.04

Comment: @ThomasWard finished installing 18.04 five minutes ago, looking at 2.7, 3.6, 3.7, Idle 3?

Comment: @JacobVlijm As I stated I looked in Ubuntu Software, nothing (relating to the Python IDE) comes up when I search for IDLE. Clearly I must be doing something wrong hence why I said I'm not interested in workarounds - other ways of installing, I want to know where I should be looking. I will pass n your offensive remark about my myopia.

Comment: @JacobVlijm `idle` and `idle3` are part of the Python source package. [`idle` requires Python 3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/idle), and [so does `idle3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/idle3)

Comment: @StephenBrown "Ubuntu Software" is a horrid piece of software to find what's actually available in the repositories.  Just putting that out there, because it *regularly* doesn't find things.

Comment: I'm beginning to get that but I (wrongly?) thought that IDLE  was as mainstream as it gets.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, I installed this package via cmd `sudo apt install idle-python3.6`.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try installing it from the command line directly, as [this other almost identical question/answer pair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660414/idle-installation-in-ubuntu-14-04) instruct you on how to do?

You can install IDLE for Python 3 with

```
sudo apt install idle
```

... or with ...

```
sudo apt install idle3
```

There is no Python2 version of IDLE in Ubuntu 18.04, however.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWard I did try sudo apt-get install idle but I think it resulted in a 'broken' install. In Show Applications two icons for IDLE were created but when I clicked on them nothing happened.

Comment: @StephenBrown what happens when you run `idle3` in the terminal directly?  Any runtime error output should show *there* if not in the GUI runtime.

Comment: Nothing happens now - I went back and reinstalled 18.04 from scratch (I had other issues). I wrongly expected IDLE to be part of a default install because Python is included.

Comment: There is something very ugly - broken here. I did sudo apt install idle. Now I get two 'icons' in Show Applications, one icon is ugly (it does not scale like all the other icons) Underneath it says... IDLE (using Pyt... If I right click, I get the Ubuntu Software window with No Applications Found in the middle. If I double click it opens Python 3.6.5 Shell. The other 'icon' is a blank space with IDLE3 underneath, if I right click, I get the Ubuntu Software window with widl-nan, IdleRPG & Power Management in a list. Double click opens Python 3.6.5 Shell same as above. Horrid!

Comment: I meant ...right click, Show Details above.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't bundle IDLE.  It's not installed by default in Ubuntu, but it is installed in other linux distributions. It's an optional part of Python.

As other stated it out, you can quickly install it with

```
sudo apt install idle
```

It is only available for Python 3.